# CMake generates VC solution with incorrect target link library prefix

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cmake, shared-libraries

I'm having trouble trying to do something seemingly very simple with CMake 2.8.11.2 . I have a folder with two files:

```
-- CMAkeLists.txt --
add_executable(test test.c) 
target_link_libraries (test somelib)


-- test.c --
// Some c code
```

when I create a build directory and issue `cmake ..`, cmake runs with the following output:

```
C:\Users\Enis\workspace_kepler\tmp\build>cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/Enis/workspace_kepler/tmp/build
```

And an MSVC 2012 solution is generated inside the build folder (as I have MSVC2012 installed). Now, the problem is that when I open that solution and check the linker configuration of the `test` project under Properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies I see that `somelib` is added as `;-lsomelib.lib` and visual studio doesn't like that. It links successfuly only if I change that to `somelib.lib` manually.

What am I doing wrong? Why does CMake make such a simple mistake? What can I do to change the prefix it generates?

Comment: Are you running CMake from a Visual Studio command prompt?  And do you initially specify Visual Studio 11 as the generator?  (`cmake .. -G"Visual Studio 11"` or `cmake .. -G"Visual Studio 11 Win64"`)

Comment: @Fraser thanks for pointing those out, but nothing changed when I've explicitly specified the generator (in the windows command prompt) nor when I've switched to the VS command prompt. Exactly the same output from CMake in the prompt, and the same result in the link option.

Comment: This seems pretty weird.  Normally if you get the "The C compiler identification is unknown" message, configuring fails and you don't end up with a .sln file.  I hope someone else can answer this for you, but in the meantime as a wild guess, you could try reinstalling Visual Studio.  Or you could try asking on the [CMake mailing list](http://www.cmake.org/mailman/listinfo/cmake).

Comment: @Fraser I've just installed MSVC 2012, but I've been installing and removing many compilers (MinGW and Cygwin etc. included) on this installation of Windows, so I wouldn't be surprized if some leftover is confusing CMake. I'll try the same on a more fresh installation, and if it works there (and on other computers) I don't mind tweaking one line in the solution file in this particular PC.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. The root of the problem is `CMAKE_LINK_LIBRARY_FLAG` but I have no idea what sets it. Resetting it, demonstrated in the snippet below, should help you.

```
set(CMAKE_LINK_LIBRARY_FLAG "")
```